# Cannot re-enable material autocomplete panel after disabling it

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I think I have found a bug in `mat-autocomplete` (or not understanding how it works) but I want to run it by you all first.

In the TS I tap the the stream of data for the filtered list, if the list is more than 6 I do not want the autocomplete panel to show.

There is an `@Input` called `AutocompleteDisabled` that takes a `boolean` according to the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api):

> Whether the autocomplete is disabled. When disabled, the element will
>   act as a regular input and the user won't be able to open the panel.

I have tried subscribing from the HTML which didnt change the result. I even tried making a checkbox that flipped the value from true to false but once I set the checkbox to false, even if I make it true again the autocomplete panel fails to work.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sample',
  templateUrl: './app-sample.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-sample.component.styl']
})
export class AppSampleComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedOption = new FormControl('');
  disablePanel = false;
  filteredOptions: Option[] = [];
  private options: Option[] = [];


  constructor(private myService: MyService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.getOptions().subscribe(data => this.options = data.carriers);
    this.selectedOption.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith<string | Option>(''),
      map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name),
      map(name => name ? this.filterByName(name) : this.options.slice()),
      tap(filtered => {
        // If ever this evelauates to true, the panel stops appearining and when it evaluates back to false
        // it is as if all of auto-complete stops working.
        this.disablePanel = filtered.length > 6;
      }
    ).subscribe(filtered => this.filteredOptions = filtered);
  }

  private filterByName(value: string): Option[] {
    return this.options.filter( => option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) === 0);
  }

}
```

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-icon matSuffix>search</mat-icon>
  <input [formControl]="selectedOption"
         placeholder="Select and Option"
         matInput
         [matAutocompleteDisabled]="disablePanel"
         [matAutocomplete]="auto">
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions " [value]="option">
      {{option.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: if possible, please create a demo over stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

Can you somehow take this code outside `ngOnInit` 
 `this.disablePanel = filtered.length < 6`;

can set is using a method like

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.myService.getOptions().subscribe(data => this.options = data.carriers);
  this.selectedOption.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith<string | Option>(''),
    map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name),
    map(name => name ? this.filterByName(name) : this.options.slice()),
    tap(filtered => {
      // If ever this evelauates to true, the panel stops appearining 
      // and when it evaluates back to false
      // it is as if all of auto-complete stops working.
      this.callAMethod(filtered);
    }
  ).subscribe(filtered => this.filteredOptions = filtered);
}

callAMethod(filtered) {
  this.disablePanel = filtered.length > 6;
}
```